# Write down P(0), P(1), P(2), P(3) and P(4) when the difference equation and initial value are as given below.

Tags: recurrence-relations

$P(t) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{t}{n})|$
$t = 0,1, . . .n$
$n \in \mathbb{N}$

I took $n$ as the number of the iteration we're currently on and then $t$ would essentially be $n-1$

Which then left me with:

$P(0) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{0}{1})| = 2.303$
$P(1) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{1}{2})| = UND$
$P(2) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{2}{3})| = 1.609$
$P(3) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{3}{4})| = 1.956$
$P(4) = ln|10cos(\pi\frac{4}{5})| = 2.091$

Am I on the right track or have I completely missed the mark?

Comment: I do not see a difference equation.  Did you forget that part?

Comment: @GEdgar This is as it was given to me. This equation is part of a set of equations that were given to me but the only one that refers to $P(t)$ instead of $P(n+1)$